# Microsoft Azure Authentication Failed & ColdFusion

Tags: azure, coldfusion, azure-blob-storage

I'm working on connecting a ColdFusion 2016 application to [Microsoft Azure blob storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx) and just don't seem to be able to get the authentication correct.

Here is the error I'm receiving:

> `<Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to
>   authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header
>   is formed correctly including the signature.
>   RequestId:9aed89ad-0001-00b8-6fd8-ecc48c000000
>   Time:2016-08-02T16:07:42.9046123Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The
>   Date header in the request is
>   incorrect.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>`
>
> HTTP/1.1 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the
>   value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the
>   signature. Content-Length: 419 Content-Type: application/xml Server:
>   Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 x-ms-request-id:
>   9aed89ad-0001-00b8-6fd8-ecc48c000000 Date: Tue, 02 Aug 2016 16:07:42
>   GMT Connection: close

Here is my code to list blobs in a container:

```
<!--- The key is copied directly from the Azure portal interface. --->
<cfset theKey = "fxIciOymaQ2OAcc1g2M...BwQRxNPtEzmwHAyx6J6pw==" />

<cfset requestMethod = "GET" />

<cfset utcDate = dateConvert("local2UTC",now()) />
<cfset xmsDate = dateFormat(utcDate,"ddd, d mmm yyyy") & " " & timeFormat(utcDate,"HH:mm:ss") & " GMT" />

<cfset xmsVersion = "2015-12-11" />

<cfset canonicalizedHeaders = "x-ms-date:#xmsDate#\nx-ms-version:#xmsVersion#\n" />
<cfset canonicalizedResource = "/coldfusion/slao\ncomp:list\ninclude:metadata,snapshots,uncommittedblobs\nrestype:container\n" />

<cfset stringToSign = "#requestMethod#\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n#canonicalizedHeaders##canonicalizedResource#" />

<cfset x = replace(stringToSign,"\n","#chr(13)##chr(10)#","all") />
<cfset y = hmac(x,tmp,"HmacSHA256","utf-8") />
<cfset requestSignature = toBase64(binaryDecode(y,"hex")) />

<cfhttp method="#requestMethod#" url="https://coldfusion.blob.core.windows.net/slao?restype=container&comp=list&include=snapshots&include=metadata&include=uncommittedblobs" result="requestResult">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="SharedKey coldfusion:#requestSignature#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="x-ms-date" value="#xmsDate#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="x-ms-version" value="#xmsVersion#">
</cfhttp>
```

The error suggests a bad date. As a test, I've copied in the date and time stamp shown in the error response and rerun my program - same error. I've spent quite a bit of time trying to research this on my own, but I just haven't made any progress on this. I've tried Fiddler as well but, of course, I'm getting the same error.

Does anyone see what the problem might be?  Any ideas would be appreciated...

Sharon

Comment: (Edit) The replace() may be part of the problem. Typically, HTTP requests *only* use `chr(10)` for new lines. So unless the API specifically instructs you to use both `chr(13)` and `chr(10)`, ie CR & LF, that could be causing a problem. Try using using `chr(10)` - only.

Comment: How are you computing `tmp` variable here: `<cfset y = hmac(x,tmp,"HmacSHA256","utf-8") />`?

Comment: @Leigh, first, thank you for correcting the formatting on my error message!  Also, I've removed the #chr(13)# and am still getting the same error.

Comment: @SharonG - Welcome.  Can you post a link to the API you used to create the code above? Also, not sure if you saw Gaurav's comment, but what is the source of the `tmp` variable used in the hmac()?

Comment: @GauaravMantri, my mistake.  The line `<cfset y = hmac(x,tmp,"HmacSHA256","utf-8") />` should read `<cfset y = hmac(x,theKey,"HmacSHA256","utf-8") />` where theKey is set at the top of the program.  I went to portal.azure.com, navigated to my "coldfusion" storage account, and then literally copied and pasted "key1" into the `<cfset>` at the top of my cfm.

Comment: @Leigh, here is the link to the authentication part of accessing the Microsoft Azure Rest API:  [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx].

Comment: @SharonG - Thanks. The only thing that jumps out at me so far is the extra `\n` at the end of the canonicalizedResource string. I think it should be  `....,uncommittedblobs\nrestype:container` instead of `....,uncommittedblobs\nrestype:container\n`.

Comment: One other thing.  The [hmac() function documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-h-im/hmac.html) is extremely poor. However, I *believe* it uses the "encoding" attribute on BOTH the input and key string. While that is correct for the input string, your key is obviously in base64 format, so decoding it as utf-8 will produce the wrong result. Instead, decode the key into binary, ie `<cfset binaryKey = binaryDecode(theKey, "base64")>`. Then use the binary key value in the hmac call, ie `hmac(x, binaryKey,"HmacSHA256","utf-8")`

Comment: @Leigh I believe your comment is correct. The key should be converted into binary format using binaryDecode.

Comment: @Leigh and @GauravMantri - adding `<cfset binaryKey = binaryDecode(theKey, "base64")>`, removing the extra `\n`, and a small tweak to the day number formatting in the date worked!

Comment: Great! (.. and thanks for posting the final code for the next guy :)

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to share my final, working program in ColdFusion 2016:

```
<!---
Copied directly from portal.azure for this storage account.
The copied value is in base64 format.
--->
<cfset theKey = "fxIciOymaQ2OAcc1g2M...BwQRxNPtEzmwHAyx6J6pw==" />

<!---
Explicitly decode the base64 key into binary, so that hmac() 
does not use the supplied "encoding", ie utf-8 to decode it
(because that produces the wrong result). 
--->
<cfset binaryKey = binaryDecode(theKey, "base64")>

<cfset requestMethod = "GET" />

<cfset utcDate = dateConvert("local2UTC",now()) />
<cfset xmsDate = dateFormat(utcDate,"ddd, dd mmm yyyy") & " " & timeFormat(utcDate,"HH:mm:ss") & " GMT" />

<cfset xmsVersion = "2015-12-11" />

<cfset canonicalizedHeaders = "x-ms-date:#xmsDate#\nx-ms-version:#xmsVersion#\n" />
<cfset canonicalizedResource = "/coldfusion/slao\ncomp:list\ninclude:metadata,snapshots,uncommittedblobs\nrestype:container" />

<cfset stringToSign = "#requestMethod#\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n#canonicalizedHeaders##canonicalizedResource#" />

<cfset x = replace(stringToSign,"\n","#chr(10)#","all") />
<cfset y = hmac(x,binaryKey,"HmacSHA256","utf-8") />
<cfset requestSignature = toBase64(binaryDecode(y,"hex")) />

<cfhttp method="#requestMethod#" url="https://coldfusion.blob.core.windows.net/slao?restype=container&comp=list&include=snapshots&include=metadata&include=uncommittedblobs" result="requestResult">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="SharedKey coldfusion:#requestSignature#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="x-ms-date" value="#xmsDate#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="x-ms-version" value="#xmsVersion#">
</cfhttp>

<cfdump var="#requestResult#" expand="yes" />
```

Many thanks!
Sharon